# Getting notifications when a selected region of my computer screen changes

Tags: windows-10, screen-recording

I need some kind of screen recording software that records a part of my screen and checks for any changes. If so, I would like to get a notification, SMS or email on my phone.

The thing that needs monitoring is a chat inside a game. When someone talks, the chat changes and I would like to get a notification.

This could be a screen recording running 24/7 or something that takes a screenshot of the selected area every X seconds and compares this one with the latest for any changes.

The PC is running Windows 10.

Comment: Do you have any pricing limitations, e.g. [tag:gratis]?

Comment: Does the chat area stay pixel-for-pixel equal otherwise? E.g. if the chat has an opaque background, it should be fine, but if it's transparent, something might happen due to idle animations or external events.

Comment: Let's say everything else stays still